# Stuck/Sticky side Navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

How do I get my sidemenu to remain stuck so the navigation tabs always remain on top and don't scroll with the page

How do I get the buttons to change background color on `hover`? 
The issue is that only the text changes `background color` or only a small portion

[THE CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYKKMR)

```
    <head>
    <title>Århus Gastronomi</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="frontpage" class="content">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <ul id="navbar">
            <li class="navitem"><a href="#">Kat</a></li>
            <li class="navitem"><a href="#">Kat</a></li>
            <li class="navitem"><a href="#">Kat</a></li>
            <li class="navitem"><a href="#">Kat</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <p>Another item</p>
</div>
<div id="page2" class="content">


    <p>This is page 2</p>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Use CSS! It is great!

Comment: I tried with some CSS, but couldn't get it to work, do you have any idea about wich CSS properties I need to apply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `position: fixed;` to your `#sidebar`

You may also want to add this:

```
.content {margin-left: 10%;}
```

And restructure your html like so, with the nav outside of the first content section::

```
<body>
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul id="navbar">
        <li class="navitem"><a href="#">Kat</a></li>
        <li class="navitem"><a href="#">Kat</a></li>
        <li class="navitem"><a href="#">Kat</a></li>
        <li class="navitem"><a href="#">Kat</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="frontpage" class="content">.......
```

This will make it so that your content isn't behind the nav you have.

Comment: Worked, Thanks a lot!

Comment: See updated answer for some more changes, If this has solved your issue  completely, feel free to mark the answer as correct :)

Comment: I managerd to use the 10% margin, but applied it to the #page2 adding it to content pushed the page to the right, but it works like a charm now thanks

Comment: heres the code for your button colors too: `.navitem:hover {background-color: red;}`

Comment: Thanks a lot Sam, you have been a really great help for me! Now I can finally move on! Thanks a lot have a great day! :)